# Printing floating point number in python

Tags: python, string, floating-point, numbers, format

How can I print the following lines of code but get a floating point number of of it instead of a rounded int?

print "Math Question: ", 100 - 25 * 3 % 4

print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Division with `/` in 2.x results in a integer if both operands are integers. Either cast one of the operands to a float first, or `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 3):

```
from __future__ import divison
```

or run Python with the `-Qnew` option

Python3 has this behaviour by default

Answer (score 1):

If you use integers, Python assumes you really mean them to be integers and does integer math. If you use floats, it will do floating point math.

Try something like this to get floating point output:

```
print 3/4.0
```

Comment: Not in 3.x, not with `from __future__ import division`, and not with `-Qnew`.